# Large bytes data issue

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am stuck at fetching data from API. When there is no image data bytes in the API it is working fine. But with image parameter key, I didn't get the response. I have tried with `AFNetworking`, `NSURLConnection`, `HTTP`  but no luck. It is working fine on Simulator but not on real device.

API Response:

```
"Image": "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",
"Name": "TEST NAME",
"ResponseMessage": "Success",
"no": 1
```

I have tried with all type of possibilities, may be I am doing something wrong. Please advice.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you tried base64Encoding and decoding? How are you requesting and getting response?

Comment: I am requesting with AFHTTPRequestOperationManager but [manager1 GET:_url parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject)
     {
        NSLog(@"Success: %@", responseObject);} responseObject is empty

Comment: Have you set responseSerializer  like  self.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];

Comment: @guru Yes, I already tried with that

Comment: Is that the full API response? It looks similar to JSON, but it's not valid as JSON because it's missing the `{}` around it to indicate that it's an object. Do you own the API? Can you modify it to return valid JSON?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I am able to resolve the issue. As the response from the server consists of text along with the bytes of image data which is in UTF-8 encoding. So to get the response, we need to define the exact Content Type in the header field i.e.

```
[request setValue:@"application/json;charset=UTF-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"content-type"];
```

Thanks everyone for your concern.